# How can I avoid options if those options are previously selected in vue js html?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

My json data for getting all inventories is

```
{
  "status": true,
  "data": [
    { "inv_id": 1, "name": "Arts" },
    { "inv_id": 2, "name": "web" },
    { "inv_id": 3, "name": "mobileapp" },
    { "inv_id": 4, "name": "ws" },
    { "inv_id": 5, "name": "aop" },
    { "inv_id": 6, "name": "bin" },
    { "inv_id": 7, "name": "webs" },
    { "inv_id": 8, "name": "hell" }
  ]
}
```

My json data which is selected already by user will be in the following format

```
{
  "data": {
    "pid": 109,
    "contact": {
      "email": "ew98@gmail.com",
      "phone": 85998472,
      "address": { "country": "India", "state": "Kerala" }
    },
    "about": "hello how are you",
    "is_featured": false,
    "avg_rating": 0,
    "total_reviews": 0,
    "reviews": [],
    "inventory": [
      {
        "item": {
          "name": "Arts",
          "category": { "name": "Education", "id": 1 },
          "id": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "review": null
  },
  "status": true
}
```

Here arts is already selected, so I need to avoid the same when I am giving an edit option. How can I able to achieve the same.

```
mounted() {
  var self = this

  data = {}
  data["auth-token"] = this.authType
  data["pid"] = this.pid

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/get/post/",
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(e) {
      if (e.status == 1) {
        self.inventory = e.data.inventory

        data = {}
        data["category"] = self.catid
        data["cat_id"] = self.catid

        $.ajax({
          url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/alpha/get/inventory/",
          data: data,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(e) {
            if (e.status == 1) {
              self.inventoryall = e.data
            }
          },
        })
      }
    },
  })
}
```

I have all inventories in inventoryall[] and inventory that is already added in inventory[].

My html code is

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Inventory
    <small>(required)</small>
  </label>
  <select
    id="basic"
    class="selectpicker"
    data-live-search="true"
    data-live-search-style="begins"
    title="Select Your Subcategory"
    v-model="inv" name="inv[]" multiple required="required"
  >
    <option v-for="sop in inventoryall" v-bind:value="sop.inv_id">{{sop.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

So, when I display the inventories here, I need to avoid the once that is already selected. Please help me to have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use the array [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
// filter loops through every item in the array and returns a new array
// if the filter function returns true, the item stays in the new array
// if the filter function returns false, the item is removed
self.inventoryall = self.inventoryall.filter(item => {
  // loop through all of the currently selected items
  for (const selectedItem of self.inventory) {
    // if we find a current item with the same ID as the selected one,
    // return false, so we don't keep the item
    if (selectedItem.id === item.inv_id) {
      return false
    }
  }
  
  // if we never find an item with a matching ID, return true to keep it
  return true
})
```

Note that this method is only available in browsers that support ES6, so use the polyfill on the MDN page if you need to support older browsers.

Another note, since you're using Vue, this would probably be a good use case for a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Comment: how can I display it in the html side the options

Comment: You're already doing that right now. If you update the `inventoryall` array (in the success callback of your second ajax call, for example) Vue should update the HTML automatically

Comment: sir, nothing happens

Comment: sir it was selectedItem.id .. Thanks for the help sir